# Стоит ли убирать Listener'ы при переходе между Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте.

Недавно обнаружил, что `ValueEventListener`, привязанный к `Firebase`, продолжал работать даже после вызова в ней `StartActivity` и последующего `finish()`. Заметно это стало, т.к. внутри был прописан вызов новой `Activity` и после каждого изменения в базе вызывался тот метод.

Получается, что все `Listener'ы`, что я создавал в `Activity` работают все время до полного выключения процесса программы, но не проявляют себя явно, т.к. просто обновляют `ArrayList'ы` в фоне. В связи с этим возник резонный вопрос: нужно ли полностью убивать `Activity` при вызове новой? На enSO вычитал, что достаточно вызывать `return` после `finish()`, но это не везде возможно. В моем случае я просто вызвал метод `removeEventListener()` для объекта `DatabaseReference` после вызова новой `Activity`.

Исходя из этих размышлений, пришел к выводу, что удалять `EventListener` нужно каждый раз при переходе на новую `Activity`. Но как работает переход на предыдущую `Activity` по нажатию кнопки "назад"? Будет ли вызван в той `Activity` метод onCreate заново? Если нет, то тогда и `Listener` заново установлен не будет.

Короче говоря, помогите разрешить мою дилемму. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте подпсываться в onResume и отписываться в onPause

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я так понимаю, что `onPause()` вызывается при при вызове новой `Activity` поверх текущей. Вызывается ли он при вызове `finish()`? Или нужно отдельно прописывать `onStop()`? И нужно ли переносить инициализацию компонентов из `onCreate` в `onResume` или в `onResume` только заново устанавливать `Listener`?

Comment: При завершении активити onPause вызовется. onStop может не понадобится. Перенос инициализации - вопрос сложный. Думаю можно попробовать ограничиться установкой слушателей в onResume

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за совет, реализовал - вроде, работает. Я думаю, можно опубликовать это как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае можно подписываться на события в onResume и отписываться в onPause - onPause вызовется при уходе с активити (не важно каков именно уход - переход на следующую активити, возвращение к предыдущей, сворачивание приложения), onResume - при активации оной.

Но надо быть аккуратным - onPause вызовется в т.ч. при открытии диалогов.

Comment: А можно еще уточнить по поводу последнего выражения? Ведь `BottomSheetDialogFragment` тоже относится к диалогом? И вызывается ли метод `onResume` после закрытия него?

UPD: сейчас проверил: при открытом `BottomSheetDialogFragment` обновление все равно идет.

Comment: @ahgpoug вы можете выводить в логи что-то из этих методов чтобы понять когда они вызываются. По идее показ диалога такого должен вызвать onPause. А после его скрытия должен вызваться onResume. Если этого не происходит - возможно это особенность реализации именно этого типа диалога.

Comment: Я как раз так и проверял. Спасибо за ответ.